# Binding Two Grids, one datatable, master: datagridview detail: ultragrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Folks, this is what I am attempting with not too much success yet:

I have one datatable that will contain the data for both the master and detail grid (dsLocal.Tables[0] global variable).  User will select a maximum of one record from the datagridview (the master).  At this point that one record should appear in the "detail" ultragrid.  The _SelectionChanged event of the datagridview will be handled to populate the ultragrid.  The following code will run:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow theDataRow = dsLocal.Tables[0].Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index];

    // Set the data source and data member to bind the grid.
    ultraGrid1.DataSource = theDataRow;
    ultraGrid1.DataMember = "";
    ...
}
```

As you can see, not only does the code above not work, the above would not work in any case since if they sort the master grid, the index counter would be off.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Before Hand

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question (Very ugly solution but it does work correctly)  If you have something better, please let me know.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{

DataRow selectedRow = ((DataRowView)this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).Row;

DataTable dt = dsLocal.Tables[0].Clone();

dt.ImportRow(selectedRow);

ultraGrid1.DataSource = dt;
ultraGrid1.DataMember = "";

}
}
```